# Please Help: Derivative of a sinc function.

Tags: derivatives, fourier-transform, signal-processing

We have been given to find the derivative of the sinc function attached below.
Provided Sinc Function
[image]

I am failed to understand that how pi appears in the derivate when it's not in the original function. Please help.

Derivative of sinc function
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Actually $\pi$ **is** in the original function, according to the definition:
$$
\operatorname{sinc} x = \frac{\sin(\pi x)}{\pi x}.
$$

Comment: In my case pi is not present in the reconstructed signal then it appears when we take a derivative?

Comment: You have the sinc function in the formula, hence you have $\pi$ too, “under the hood” so to speak.